# Cell value is always empty in RowCancelingEdit event in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using `GridView` with `AutoGenerateEditButton="True"`  which gives me edit functionality. My problem is, if I want to get cell value in `RowEditing` event than I can get it by using `grdEmpDetail.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[2].Text` but if I want to get cell value in `RowCancelingEdit` event than `grdEmpDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text` is always empty.

How can I get the `Cell value` in `RowCancelingEdit` event?

**CODE:**

```
protected void grdEmpDetail_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    //Reset the edit index.
    this.grdEmpDetail.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    WorkSampleBusiness.BusinessObject objBL = new WorkSampleBusiness.BusinessObject();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(grdEmpDetail.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[2].Text)) //This gives me current cell value
    {
        lastName = grdEmpDetail.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[2].Text;
        DataBindGrid(objBL.EmployeeDetails(lastName));
    }
    else
        DataBindGrid(objBL.EmployeeDetails(lastName));
}

protected void grdEmpDetail_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    //Reset the edit index.
    this.grdEmpDetail.EditIndex = -1;
    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    WorkSampleBusiness.BusinessObject objBL = new WorkSampleBusiness.BusinessObject();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(grdEmpDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text)) // This is always empty
    {
        lastName = grdEmpDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
        DataBindGrid(objBL.EmployeeDetails(lastName));
    }
    else
        DataBindGrid(objBL.EmployeeDetails(lastName));
}
```

Comment: I guess make a global variable initialize it in `grdEmpDetail_RowEditing` and use it in `grdEmpDetail_RowCancelingEdit`. Couldn't find any better.If you do, pls post

Comment: I Think I've to go that way. Thanks for sharing your view.